# How to get my staticTableViewCell to automatically size itself based on the imageView and not the label

Tags: ios, swift

My app cells are static and when i try to have them autosize themselves it always stay the same height or sizes to where the label ends when i need it to size to the bottom of the images. I have tried heightForRowAt, automaticHeight, and estimatedHeight, but none of them work. Does anyone have any idea how to make this work?

```
class BillInfoTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var billInfoNumberLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var billInfoNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var billInfoSummaryLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var billInfoHouseImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var billInfoSenateImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var billInfoPresidentImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var billInfoProgressView: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var latestActionDateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sponsorNameLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var billInfoHouseHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var billInfoHouseWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var billInfoSenateWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var billInfoSenateHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var billInfoPresidentWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var billInfoPresidentHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var billInfoHouseTopBillNameBottom: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var billInfoSenateTopBillNameBottom: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var billInfoPresidentTopBillNameBottom: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var billInfo: Bill?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let billInfo = billInfo {
            billInfoNumberLabel?.text = "\(billInfo.number)"
            billInfoNameLabel?.text = "\(billInfo.shortTitle)"
            billInfoSummaryLabel?.text = "\(billInfo.summary)"
            latestActionDateLabel?.text = "\(billInfo.latestActionDate)"
            sponsorNameLabel?.text = "\(billInfo.sponsorName)"
            
            
            
            if billInfo.summary.isEmpty {
                billInfoSummaryLabel?.text = "Summary N/A"
            }
        }
        updateImage(bill: billInfo!)
        
        
    }
    
    func updateImage(bill: Bill) {
        
        if let house = bill.house  {
            billInfoHouseImage.image = UIImage(named: "BlueHouse")
            billInfoHouseWidth.constant = 85
            billInfoHouseHeight.constant = 87
            billInfoHouseTopBillNameBottom.constant = 1
            
        } else {
            billInfoHouseImage.image = UIImage(named: "GreyHouse")
            billInfoHouseWidth.constant = 93
            billInfoHouseHeight.constant = 103
        }
        
        if let senate = bill.senate  {
            billInfoSenateImage.image = UIImage(named: "BlueSenate")
            billInfoSenateWidth.constant = 103
            billInfoSenateHeight.constant = 118
            billInfoSenateTopBillNameBottom.constant = -17
            
        } else {
            billInfoSenateImage.image = UIImage(named: "GreySenate")
            billInfoSenateWidth.constant = 86
            billInfoSenateHeight.constant = 80
            billInfoSenateTopBillNameBottom.constant = -5
        }
        
        if let enacted = bill.enacted  {
            billInfoPresidentImage.image = UIImage(named: "BluePresident")
            billInfoPresidentWidth.constant = 117
            billInfoPresidentHeight.constant = 117
            billInfoPresidentTopBillNameBottom.constant = -19
            
        } else {
            billInfoPresidentImage.image = UIImage(named: "GreyPresident")
            billInfoPresidentWidth.constant = 109
            billInfoPresidentHeight.constant = 99
        }
    }
}
```

What the tableView looks like in simulator when the top cell is sized right in storyboard:

[image]

What the tableView looks like in simulator when top cell needs more room:

[image]

What the tableView looks like in simulator when top cell has to much room:

[image]

Comment: This is a bit confusing... have you created a table view controller with **Static Cells** in Storyboard, and created IBOutlets and constraints directly in your `UITableViewController` class? And, is `billInfoProgressView : UIProgressView` the horizontal line going through the centers of the round images?

Comment: Yes i created a tableViewController with static cells, i create constrants inc code for the imageViews, and i the horizontal line is a progressView

Comment: OK - dynamic / auto-sizing cell height is tough to accomplish with Static cells. It will be ***much*** easier if you use dynamic custom cells. It's not clear why you are changing the image sizes though... are they supposed to change size or just color?

Comment: The grey images and blue images are not all the same size originally so when it changes between images they need to change sizes so tthey look mlike there all the same size.

Comment: First, as I said, you almost certainly want to use custom cells instead of Static cells. Also, I strongly suggest you edit your images to make them the same size, and put the imageViews in a stackView (with `Equal Spacing`). With proper auto-layout setup, you won't have to do ***ANY*** size calculations / adjustments.